# Avoid waiting for short text speech recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, gboard

When I use Google speech recognition on the keyboard with a short sentence, I have to wait on Google to know this is the end of dictation.

example : I tap the microphone, then I say just "ok, it's noted". I have to wait about 5 seconds. If I touch microphone icon, it stops the recognition and nothing is inserted.

Is there a way to force the end of dictation and the recognition of the short text I have pronounced ?

Comment: Maybe something here can help https://support.google.com/android/thread/22906479/how-do-i-get-voice-typing-to-to-type-a-period-question-mark?hl=en